# How to get the type of Akka Actors?

Tags: java, akka, akka-actor

How does one validate the type of actors that are created?

I encountered an issue, where I created the wrong actor. I am using guice to create actors and therefore creation is decoupled from business logic.

The root cause of the issue was me creating an Actor (let's call him X) instead of a RouterActor that forwards to actors of type X.

Thus everything looked fine for correctness testing, but the service failed when hitting higher load and timeouts where blocking the actor.

#### Approaches so far

1. do not test (this is what actually caused the issue)
2. test by getting the actor-path of the response (this seems unnecessarily convoluted)
3. set a performance objective and do not test the implementation but check if the objective holds. i.e.: for 100 requests per second where 10% of the requests time out guarantee a response latency.